# Which is better ECDHE with TLS 1.0

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, perfect-secrecy

I have a webserver which only supports TLS 1.0 and I am not sure about something: Which is the better cipher in this group when aiming for the best security?

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc007)
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc011)
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc008)
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc012)
```

I chose only ciphers with `ECDHE` for Perfect Forward Secrecy. Speed is not very important, for me secure is more important.

These ciphers are used in my Java application for retrieving data from a HTTPS website. My doubt was due to the fact that the CBC Ciphers are vulnerable to BEAST Attacks.

Comment: I'm assuming you don't really want NULL as that means no confidentiality (in other words your data is sent unencrypted). I'd avoid RC4. As to what is left, what are your goals? How important is speed? In other words, what does "better" mean? Does your processor support AES-NI? Why only SHA and nothing from SHA2 family?

Comment: At minimum you can eliminate 3DES, it's strictly worse than AES. And `NULL` is obviously not useful either when you're interested in confidentiality.

Comment: Well, if you are interested in "best security", you should probably use anything with AES and SHA at the end, the rest is kinda personal preference: AES 128 and AES 256 are both considered secure, it depends mostly on how large your blocks should be. Choosing RSA or ECDSA as signature algorithm is both fine (it depends more on the according parameters to achieve a secure level)

Comment: @tylo: nit: AES-128 and AES-256 has the same block size; they differ in the size of their keys.

Comment: I know AES 256 is better. But with TLS 1.0 CBC Ciphers are vulnerable to Beast Attack. My processor not support AES-NI. My application is developed with java 7 and the list of cipher is extracted from DefaultCipherSupported.

Comment: @GiovanniNervi *Some* clients are vulnerable to BEAST. The rest have implemented workarounds even on TLS 1.0. I consider BEAST to be a smaller issue than RC4 sucking.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Any detail or pointer to what substantiates your feeling that RC4 is a worst risk that CBC, given the existence of BEAST? I have no informed opinion about that.

Comment: @fgrieu 1) Most browsers mitigate BEAST, even on TLS 1.0 2) BEAST (like all other attacks based on TLS using MtE instead of EtM) is inherently an active attack. RC4 has some weaknesses even against passive attacks. 3) BEAST seems to be tricky to exploit in practice. The original attack [needed browser features/bugs no longer present](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/24932/3826).

Comment: @CodesInChaos: All this, especially "RC4 has some weaknesses even against **passive** attacks", makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The best option you have is `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA`**.
 This is likely to provide most security, as the AES keylength is maximal and ECDSA keys tend to provide more security than RSA keys, as a 128-bit security level is quite common with ECDSA (field size: 256 bit) whereas 112-bit is the standard with RSA (keylength: 2048 bit).

However in practice `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA` may be easier to deploy as RSA certificates are usually a lot cheaper and easier to get.

To get even further you're also fine with `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` and `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` as a 128-bit key is quite common today and chances are your ECDH group also provides "only" 128-bit security, meaning you can get higher speed without sacrificing security.

As explained in the comments by [CodesInChaos](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/180/codesinchaos) you should definitely avoid RC4, which is also officially banned from TLS as per [RFC 7465](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7465). To repeat what CodesInChaos said:
The CBC-suites are less an issue than RC4 because ...

1. modern browsers mitiagate BEAST (CBC-based attack) even on TLS 1.0
2. BEAST is an active attack, whereas RC4 already falls due to *passive* attacks
3. BEAST is hard to exploit in practice and relevant features s[eem to have been removed](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10481/next-microsoft-patch-tuesday-include-beast-ssl-fix/24932#24932).

This removes the `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA` and `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA` ciphersuites from the list. You should also avoid 3DES, as it provides "only" 112-bit security, but is significantly slower than AES making it inferior in every aspect, so you shouldn't choose `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA` nor `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA`.

**However, if possible you should migrate to TLS v1.2 (or newer)**. There you should avoid all cipher suites not finishing with `..._SHA256` or `_SHA384` as the other ones use SHA-1 which is deprecated. Furthermore TLS v1.2 (or newer) allows (v1.3 will force) you to use non-CBC mode ciphers, especially AEAD ciphers, which don't suffer from BEAST or similar attacks. This means that as of now the best choice (in terms of security) for the cipher suite is `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`, with `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` not being a lot weaker. If possible you should prefer ECDSA (or EdDSA) over RSA although RSA can be sufficiently secure when using appropriate keylengths.

Comment: Voted this up, but please make sure that the analysis is still valid in the future, and try to move to TLS 1.2 or 1.3 (when it is out) if you can.

Comment: And although Java, as identified in the Q, was and is not a browser, it also implemented in 2011 the 1/n mitigation for 1.0 (and pre-POODLE SSL3) CBC. (More recently in 2021 Java default-disabled 1.0 and 1.1 entirely.)

Answer (score -1):

If your client use modern browser such as the latest chrome or firefox you should choose TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (If you use ECDSA certificates)OR TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (If you use RSA certificates)
If your client use old browser such as Internet Explorer or old system such as Windows XP may be TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA or TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA are better choice because these things can fix beast attack

Comment: As explained in the long-existing answer and comments BEAST hasn't been a problem since 2012 and RC4 is broken worse than anything but single-DES (or export, which was broken by design). And XP didn't (doesn't?) support either ECDHE or ECDSA at all. (Some versions of Firefox around 2012-2014 might, since Firefox doesn't use schannel, but TTBOMK modern Firefox won't even install on XP.)

Comment: In my opinion if the client use tls 1.0 or the earlier protocol they won't upgrade their software or system so they won't fix the BEAST i think it's worse than rc4 cipher if they upgrade their software or system they will use  tls1.1 or 1.2